# TFS 2008 : How to make Source Control Explorer show "ADD" operations for other users?

Tags: tfs

In the visual studio Source Control Explorer window, I can see my own "add" operations, but do not see the "add" operations for other users. I can see all other operations (rename, edit, etc), but cannot see any add's.

Anyone know how to turn this on, or how to view add's otherwise?

Comment: When you add you haven't committed. You want other users to see something that is not committed?

Comment: Yes, to make sure that users who are checking in sequentially named files (SQL data updates, etc) arent stepping on each other's file names.

Comment: When you edit, you haven't committed either.

Comment: @StingyJack- I've never been in a situation where that has been an issue, but for you it is so I'm glad you've found an acceptable answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a way to view other people's pending adds.  The items shown in SCE represent the latest state on the server, modulo any changes that are pending in the currently selected workspace.  In other words, if you switch to another workspace in the dropdown at the top, you won't even see *your own* pending adds.

Closest substitute I can think of is the "Team Members" feature introduced in the Fall '08 [power tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/teamsystem/bb980963.aspx).  In short, you can quickly view anyone's pending changes (along with shelvesets & checkin history) by right clicking on their name in Team Explorer.

Comment: Thanks, the team members works well enough for what we need it for.